# how to remove fieldset from date input

Tags: entities, datetime

I set up a site in drupal, and I need to show the fields of date type in the same way as other fields. the problem is that those fields are inside a fieldset.

I'm try the solution [code karate](http://codekarate.com/blog/removing-fieldset-drupal-7-date-field), buts it only changes the fieldset to a label.

[image: my attempt]

What I want is showing those fields outside a fieldset, stay equal to the remaining fields.

I am using the following code.

```
/**
 * Remove fieldset from date inputs
 */
function mytheme_date_combo($variables) {
    dd($variables);
    return theme('form_element', $variables);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just hide the label with CSS, `#edit-field-data-de-nascimento .form-type-date-combo label { display:none; }`?

Comment: because resolve this problem with css is a bad practice. users may have deactivated the css.

Comment: are you serious? :) This sounds really funny. Which user deactivates using CSS? 0.01% of the users? If the user keeps the CSS disabled, he/she will experience larger "problems" (?) than seeing the form element's label. Not to mention that even the core CSS stylesheets hide many information with using regular CSS to keep some information still readable by screen readers!! **So NO, resolving this issue with CSS is NOT a bad practice.**

Comment: these you to forget the users that use accessibility programs

Comment: NO, I didn't forget about users that use accessibility programs, **this is exactly what I was talking about** when saying _Not to mention that even the core CSS stylesheets hide many information with using regular CSS to keep some information still readable by screen readers!_

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove fieldset from date field](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52255/remove-fieldset-from-date-field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you try this way

[`hook_form_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)

> Perform alterations before a form is rendered.
>
> One popular use of this hook is to add form elements to the node form.
>   When altering a node form, the node object can be accessed at
>   $form['#node'].

This is the idea

```
<?php
function example_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // If Devel Installed 
  dsm($form_id);  // print form ID to messages
  dsm($form);  // pretty print array using Krumo to messages
  // If no Devel
  print $form_id;
  // 1. Find the From ID of the Form
  // 2. Check the Form Structure and Remove the Field Set.
}
?>
```

Here is [Form API Reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7)

Comment: `hook_form_alter()` is preferable than implementing a theme function that would alter a form element in any form using it.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, sorry i dont understand. Can you elaborate ? Can we move to chat ?

Comment: I am just saying that your solution is better than implementing `theme_date_combo()` as the OP is doing. `theme_date_combo()` alters how the date field is rendered for every form. It is more probable the OP needs to alter specific date fields in specific forms, rather than changing every date field.

Comment: thx for reply. My goal was even modify all fields of date type, ie, remove the fieldset, replacing the legend with a normal label, and remove the label that is inside the fieldset.

Answer (score 3):

I used a patch from an issue queue in drupal to sort me out on that one. I should say it works well for me. You can find it [here](http://drupal.org/node/1467712#comment-6137556)